# override .equals() on a customer object

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I want to override equals on a custom object and want to check whether the current object is equal to the one passed in the parameter by Id (getId). How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Show a sample of your code please.

Comment: Generally `equals` should compare the *relevant members* of both objects to determine equality ..

Comment: If you are unsure, a good alternative is to let your IDE do it for you.

Comment: You can't do this until you define what you mean by "equal".  Do you mean only the IDs are equal, without considering any other members?  Do you want "deep equal", which compares all data members and _their_ members recursively? Only some?  There's no way to answer this question without more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to give you an answer with only the information you've provided. But you want something roughly like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (! (o instanceof MyClass)) return false;
    return id == ((MyClass)o).getId();
}
```

Where `id` is your data field (presumably an `int`) and `MyClass` is the name of your class.

**As a note:** If you override `equals`, it is strongly encouraged that you also override [`hashCode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29). If `id` is indeed an integer, then you might consider having `hashCode` just return `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type and "nullness" of the incoming object.  You should also check whether or not `this.id` is null just to be thorough.  You also are probably going to want to override `Object.hashCode()` as well so that `Set`s and `Map`s work like you want.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if ((obj == null) || (!getClass().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))) {
    return false;
  } 

  if (this.id == null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return this.id.equals((ClassName)obj.getId());
  }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.id.hashCode();
}
```